# Swift 3 Update the variable which represents the time interval between a function being called

Tags: swift, function, time, swift3, nstimer

I have created a function and it is called every 27 seconds. The code for calling the variable is as follows

```
_ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: time, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.method), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

The variable `time` is multiplied by 0.95 in the function method but the variable time is still not updated.

Comment: Check whether that method is calling or not.

Comment: I am sorry what do you mean? the method is being called but it is called every 27 seconds not the update version of the variable

Comment: Please show us the method and its code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`timeInterval` you have specify with `scheduledTimer` is remain constant for that scheduled `Timer` object if you want to change time then you need to schedule it again in that calling function like this.

```
 _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: time, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.method), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

 func method() {
     //Do your task
     time += 0.95 //increase timer
     //Schedule it again
     _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: time, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.method), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
 }
```

Comment: You need to invalidate the timer first otherwise you will end up with several timers on each method call.

Comment: @zisoft Check properly i have set repeats to false'

Comment: one problem: it says cannot assign value of type timer to int

Comment: @ArthurMacpherson Where you are getting this?

Answer (score 0):

```
func increaseTime() {

   time += 0.95 // This will increase the time by 0.95 every time this function is called

   // Then call the function again to update the time
   _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: time, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.method), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

make sure that your variable is a `var` not a `let` or `const` because constant variables cannot be edited.